# How to convert Image from a Picturebox(Image in VB6) to String(Base64)?

Tags: sql, image, vb6

Good Morning.

I have a program in vb6 that has a control named Image3, now to have this control an image, I have to browse a picture for it preferably `.jpg` file because i will save it in my SQL now I dont need to do that because in the near future the system will go slow because a lot of image will be surely saved. The best way to do (for me) is to convert it to string and vice versa. Honestly I dont want to ask this question because it is searchable and the codes I see that will fit to it is `IO.MemoryStream` my problem is I cant see it in the references. Now I try to download a new one but the VB6 doesnt accept it.

Can someone light me up with this one? Other way to convert image to string.

The reason why im doing this is i will use the image that converted to string in my select command because the memorystream are the uniqueness of the image.

In general I dont want to upload the same image ever again.

TYSM

Comment: Firstly, if your code is VB6 then why have you added a VB.NET tag? Are you trying to mislead us deliberately or do you just not care if you waste our time? Secondly, why exactly do you think that saving images in a database is going to be slow but saving a text representation of those images is miraculously not going to be?  Just search the web for how to save an image to a database in VB6 and you won't get any VB.NET results and then you won't waste your time or ours with irrelevancies.

Comment: Sorry for that I will remove the tag VB.Net

Comment: I just dont need to save the image literally, I just want to save its string ang convert it back to image again

Comment: And why exactly do you think that would be beneficial? There's not going to be an actual picture sitting in the database. It will be binary data that is stored either way. That data can either represent the image or it can represent text that was somehow generated from the image. The binary representation of the text will be no smaller and may be bigger than the binary representation of the image, so what are you actually gaining?

Comment: Okay sir your right can you please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: I've never used VB6 so I don't know, which is why it's annoying that you lured me here with the VB.NET tag.  Like I said, search the web for how to save an image to a database in VB6 specifically.  I'm fairly certain someone will have done it before.  I just searched and found several relevant results.  Why can't you do something so easy as that?

Comment: Noted sir, Sorry for the disturbance, I feel sad that I make you angry with it :(

Comment: I spend lots of time here and elsewhere helping people with genuine issues, as do many others. It's a waste of our time if we end up telling people stuff they can easily find with a proper web search.  It's a waste of your time too.  It is much faster for you to get the information you need from the web with proper searches than waiting for strangers to answer questions. You may not think so but, if you do it properly, it certainly is.

Comment: Sounds like converting the image to base64 would be a nice simple way to do it.

Comment: @Dom how can i convert it sir?

Comment: VB6 doesn't naively have the ability to get the raw data of something like an image to save to a SQL database.  It may be easier to save the image to disk and then store the file location into the database instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already done with the this question and to those want the same as I did here is the full code.

```
Private Sub Image3_DblClick()

CommonDialog1.InitDir = App.Path
CommonDialog1.FileName = ""
CommonDialog1.Filter = "Image files|*.jpg;"
CommonDialog1.DialogTitle = "All Picture Files"
CommonDialog1.ShowOpen

If CommonDialog1.FileName <> "" Then

        Dim arrImageByte() As Byte
        Dim bytBuf() As Byte
        Dim fNum As Integer
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim strPhotoPath As String
        Dim FileInputData As String
        Dim s As String

        Image3.Picture = LoadPicture(CommonDialog1.FileName)
        strPhotoPath = CommonDialog1.FileName

        ReDim arrImageByte(FileLen(strPhotoPath))
        fNum = FreeFile()
        Open strPhotoPath For Binary As #fNum
        Get #fNum, , arrImageByte
        Close fNum

        Open CommonDialog1.FileName For Binary As #1
        FileInputData = String(LOF(1), 0)
        Get #1, 1, FileInputData
        Close #1

        bytBuf = FileInputData

        s = CryptoBase64.Encode(bytBuf)

        Text8.Text = s

        Close

End If



--------------------------Class Module------------------------------

Option Explicit
Private Const CLASS_EXCEPT_BASE As Long = &H8004E300

Public Enum CryptoBase64ExceptEnum
  cbxGetOSVersFailed = CLASS_EXCEPT_BASE
  cbxNotNT
  cbxWinXPOrLaterReqd
  cbxWinVistaOrLaterReqd
  cbxStringToBinaryFailed
  cbxBinaryToStringFailed
End Enum

Public Enum Base64FormatEnum
  bfmtCrLF = 0
  bfmtLfOnly
  bfmtNone
End Enum

Public Enum OSVersionEnum
  osvWinXP = 501
  osvWinVista = 600
End Enum

Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT As Long = 2

Private Type OSVERSIONINFO
  dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
  dwMajorVersion As Long
    ' Operating System     Value
    ' Windows 3.1            3
    ' Windows 95             4
    ' Windows 98             4
    ' Windows Me             4
    ' Windows NT 3.51        3
    ' Windows NT 4.0         4
    ' Windows 2000           5
    ' Windows XP             5
    ' Windows .Net Server    5
    ' Windows 2003 Server    5
    ' Windows 2003 R2 Server 5
    ' Windows Vista          6
    ' Windows 2008 Server    6
  dwMinorVersion As Long
    ' Operating System     Value
    ' Windows 3.1            1
    ' Windows 95             0
    ' Windows 98             10
    ' Windows Me             90
    ' Windows NT 3.51        51
    ' Windows NT 4.0         0
    ' Windows 2000           0
    ' Windows XP             1
    ' Windows .Net Server    1
    ' Windows 2003 Server    2
    ' Windows 2003 R2 Server 2
    ' Windows Vista          0
    ' Windows 2008 Server    0
    dwBuildNumber As Long
    dwPlatformId As Long
    szCSDVersion As String * 128

  'Extended information (optional), i.e. OSVERSIONINFOEX:
  wServicePackMajor As Integer
  wServicePackMinor As Integer
  wSuiteMask As Integer
  wProductType As Byte
    ' Operating System     Value
    ' NT Workstation         1
    ' NT Domain Controller   2
    ' NT Server              3
  wReserved As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function GetVersionEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetVersionExA" (lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As Long

Private Const CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 As Long = 1
Private Const CRYPT_STRING_NOCR As Long = &H80000000
Private Const CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF As Long = &H40000000

Private Declare Function CryptBinaryToString Lib "Crypt32" Alias "CryptBinaryToStringW" _
 (ByRef pbBinary As Byte, _
  ByVal cbBinary As Long, _
  ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
  ByVal pszString As Long, _
  ByRef pcchString As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptStringToBinary Lib "Crypt32" Alias "CryptStringToBinaryW" _
 (ByVal pszString As Long, _
  ByVal cchString As Long, _
  ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
  ByVal pbBinary As Long, _
  ByRef pcbBinary As Long, _
  ByRef pdwSkip As Long, _
  ByRef pdwFlags As Long) As Long

Private m_OSVersion As OSVersionEnum
Private m_lngBase64Format As Long
Public Property Get Base64Format() As Base64FormatEnum
 If m_lngBase64Format = 0 Then
   Base64Format = bfmtCrLF
 ElseIf m_lngBase64Format = CRYPT_STRING_NOCR Then
   Base64Format = bfmtLfOnly
 Else
   Base64Format = bfmtNone
 End If
End Property
Public Property Let Base64Format(ByVal Format As Base64FormatEnum)
 If Format = bfmtLfOnly Then
   If m_OSVersion < osvWinXP Then
     Err.Raise cbxWinXPOrLaterReqd, "CryptoBase64.Base64Format", "This format is only supported in Windows XP/2003 and later"
   Else
     m_lngBase64Format = CRYPT_STRING_NOCR
   End If
 ElseIf Format = bfmtNone Then
   If m_OSVersion < osvWinVista Then
     Err.Raise cbxWinVistaOrLaterReqd, "CryptoBase64.Base64Format", "This format is only supported in Windows Vista/2008 and later"
   Else
     m_lngBase64Format = CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF
   End If
 Else
   m_lngBase64Format = 0
 End If
End Property
Public Function Decode(ByRef Base64Buf As String) As Byte()
 Dim lngOutLen As Long
 Dim dwActualUsed As Long
 Dim bytBuf() As Byte

 ' Determine output buffer length required. Note:
 ' StrPtr(vbNullString) is just a way to get a null pointer,
 ' even though we're really talking about a Byte array here.
 CryptStringToBinary StrPtr(Base64Buf), _
                     Len(Base64Buf), _
                     CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, _
                     StrPtr(vbNullString), _
                     lngOutLen, _
                     0&, _
                     dwActualUsed

 ' Convert Base64 to binary.
 ReDim bytBuf(lngOutLen - 1)

 If CryptStringToBinary(StrPtr(Base64Buf), _
                        Len(Base64Buf), _
                        CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, _
                        VarPtr(bytBuf(0)), _
                        lngOutLen, _
                        0&, _
                        dwActualUsed) = 0 Then
   Err.Raise cbxStringToBinaryFailed, "CryptoBase64.Decode", "CryptStringToBinary failed, error " & CStr(Err.LastDllError)
 Else
   Decode = bytBuf
 End If

 'Open App.Path & "\MyTestGif.gif" For Binary As #1
 'Put #1, 1, Decode
 'Close #1


End Function
Public Function Encode(ByRef BinaryBuf() As Byte) As String
 Dim bytBuf() As Byte
 Dim lngOutLen As Long
 Dim strBase64 As String

 'Determine Base64 output String length required.
 CryptBinaryToString BinaryBuf(0), _
                     UBound(BinaryBuf) + 1, _
                     CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 Or m_lngBase64Format, _
                     StrPtr(vbNullString), _
                     lngOutLen

 'Convert binary to Base64.
 Encode = String(lngOutLen, 0)

 If CryptBinaryToString(BinaryBuf(0), _
                        UBound(BinaryBuf) + 1, _
                        CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 Or m_lngBase64Format, _
                        StrPtr(Encode), _
                        lngOutLen) = 0 Then

   Err.Raise cbxBinaryToStringFailed, "CryptoBase64.Encode", "CryptBinaryToString failed, error " & CStr(Err.LastDllError)
    End If
End Function
Public Property Get OSVersion() As OSVersionEnum
 OSVersion = m_OSVersion
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 Dim osvinfData As OSVERSIONINFO

 With osvinfData
   .dwOSVersionInfoSize = Len(osvinfData)
   .szCSDVersion = ""

   If GetVersionEx(osvinfData) = 0 Then
     Err.Raise cbxGetOSVersFailed, "CryptoBase64 Initialize", "GetVersionEx failed, error " & CStr(Err.LastDllError)
   End If

   If .dwPlatformId <> VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT Then
     Err.Raise cbxNotNT, "CryptoBase64 Initialize", "CryptoAPI is only available on NT-based OSs"
   End If

   m_OSVersion = .dwMajorVersion * 100 + .dwMinorVersion
 End With

 Base64Format = bfmtCrLF
End Sub
```

Just add picbox,button and and a module for this to work